# Why is there a low-res icon on the dock when Spotify is running?

Tags: plank, icons, spotify

I installed Spotify client using the method from their official site. When I run it, however, a low-res icon pop out on the dock and is used to maximise/minimise the app instead of the original hi-res icon. Any idea why this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, Plank is unable to match the Spotify window to the original launcher's .desktop file. It's using a "fallback" icon from the window itself. This seems to be something that happens fairly often on cross-platform, non-native apps like Spotify, Chrome, Minecraft, etc.

I haven't tried it myself, but supposedly you can fix it by modifying Spotify's .desktop (stored in /usr/share/applications) by changing the line `Exec=spotify %U` to `Exec=spotify`

Be aware that this may affect Spotify's ability to accept arguments from the command line or other features involving opening external files. For more information, you can see [this explanation of what `%U` does](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30210/what-does-u-mean-when-calling-a-command).

Comment: Hi Daniel! Your method works. Thank you so much. If you don't mind, can you explain a bit about the last line you mentioned? I'm still a newbie in Linux, so I can't really get what you mean. And also, if next time I face the same problem again with those cross-platform, non-native apps, I can solve it using the same way right?

Comment: @Caesium95 There's an [explanation on AskUbuntu of what %U does](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30210/what-does-u-mean-when-calling-a-command). So removing it may affect that functionality. This is what solved the mismatch for Spotify, but it may not be a solution that will work for other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your `/usr/share/icons` if you have an icon for Spotify

1. If it’s there then just open the Spotify’s .desktop file in a text editor & change the “Icon = some_name“  some_name with icon name in the /usr/share/icons.
2. If it’s not there then just copy paste a Spotify icon there.